# Windows 10 adds ---open-url to registry value for default program open command

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, file-association, visual-studio-code

I am running Windows 10.1803, build 17134.320. I am trying to get .asp files to open with VS Code. I went through the normal process, but no matter what, Windows would always ask me what program I wanted to use when I tried to open an ASP file.

So, I looked up the articles, and they said I basically had to edit the Windows registry manually. I can't find the article that I used as a reference, but it was a Microsoft doc. It said to have the file extension link to your program key, and then have your program key have the shell command, like so:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    .asp
        (Default) - vscode
        OpenWithProgids
            (Default) - (value not set)
            VisualStudio binding
            sublime
    vscode
        DefaultIcon
            (Default) - (value not set)
        shell
            open
                command
                    (Default) - "C:\Users\tschwab\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" -r "%1"
```

I did the same thing with .txt files and Sublime (because I had the same problem there), and it worked like a charm. But, for some reason, when I open an ASP file, Windows often edits the registry value for vscode. It becomes:

```
vscode
    (Default) - URL:vscode
    URL Protocol - 
    DefaultIcon
        (Default) - (value not set)
    shell
        open
            command
                (Default) - "C:\Users\tschwab\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --open-url -- "%1"
```

So, three changes. The default value of the root is added, a value of "Url Protocol" is added, and the command is modified. After this, opening a file in Windows explorer no longer works. If I edit the command back, it works again.

So, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13919). I had created the custom registry key `vscode`, but Electron was editing it behind VS Code's back. I didn't notice that a key already existed named `VSCodeSourceFile` that was precisely what I needed. I remapped the .asp binding from `vscode` to `VSCodeSourceFile`, and this worked.